# Задача по SQL - Join + Where(Having) + Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывести отсортированный по количеству перелетов (по убыванию) список пассажиров, совершивших хотя бы 1 полет.

Поля в результирующей таблице: name, count

Ссылка на задачу - https://sql-academy.org/ru/trainer/tasks/16

Попытка решения

```
SELECT name, COUNT(trip) as count
FROM
  Passenger
  JOIN Pass_in_trip on Passenger.id = Pass_in_trip.passenger
Where
  trip >= 1  
GROUP
  BY name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Система говорит, что решение не верное, хотя мне кажется, что все верно.

Comment: `time_in`, `time_out` это даты путешествий? могут тут быть запланированные путешествия, которые еще не состоялись? то есть некоторая "бронь" рейсов, по факту еще не совершенных ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верным решением будет такой простой запрос ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c75e7adeca56de81647bfea9a731f401)):

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count
FROM Passenger
JOIN Pass_in_trip on Pass_in_trip.passenger = Passenger.id
JOIN Trip on Trip.id = Pass_in_trip.trip and Trip.time_out <= now()
GROUP BY Passenger.id, Passenger.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

---

<sub>Не верно группировать только по имени пассажира, так как у разных людей имена могут совпадать, надо по идентификатору и имени.</sub>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115127/discussion-on-answer-by-norbornen---sql-join-wherehaving-group-b).

Answer (score 1):

Вот это правильный запрос. Не надо джоинить таблицу Trip

```html
SELECT DISTINCT name, COUNT(Pass_in_trip.trip) as count FROM Passenger
LEFT JOIN  Pass_in_trip ON Passenger.id = Pass_in_trip.passenger
GROUP BY Passenger.id HAVING count >= "1"
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT name,COUNT(Trip.id) as count   
FROM Passenger 
JOIN Pass_in_trip ON Passenger.id=Pass_in_trip.passenger 
JOIN Trip on Trip.id=Pass_in_trip.trip
GROUP BY Passenger.name
HAVING COUNT(Trip.id)>=1
ORDER BY count desc,name ASC
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Код это хорошо, но ответ должен быть более развернутый https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Where
  trip >= 1
```

`Pass_in_trip.trip` соответствует полю `Trip.id`, т.е. вы проверяете тут, что `id` некоего перелёта в таблице перелётов >= 1, а вовсе не число перелётов конкретного пассажира, как вы думаете.

Answer (score 0):

У меня получился чуть более лаконичный ответ:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) as count from Passenger
INNER JOIN Pass_in_trip ON Passenger.id = Pass_in_trip.passenger
GROUP BY Passenger.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

В таблице `Pass_in_trip` уже только те пассажиры у которых был хоть 1 рейс, так что не нужно делать допонительные проверки и джоинить другие таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) as count FROM Passenger, Pass_in_trip 
WHERE Pass_in_trip.passenger= Passenger.id  
GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(count) >= 1 
ORDER BY  count  DESC
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развёрнутые ответы: постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.